# How to express the following piecewise function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

How can I implement with numpy the following piecewise function and its derivative?:

[image]

I tried to:

```
def func(n):
    return beta * ((0 < n) * n + (n <= 0) * (k * np.exp(n) - alpha))
```

with its derivative (back propagation):

```
def func_prime(n)
    return (n <= 0) * np.multiply(beta ,k, np.exp(n)) + (beta)
```

However its not working. Thus, how can I implement the above function with numpy (note that n is an array).

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: You should elaborate on what is not "working", because at least your first function runs in my interpreter. Maybe you're looking for [`np.piecewise()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) ?

Comment: What is ```K``` in your formula? It looks like function. Also, you function f(n) is not defined for (0;1] What values should it return?

Comment: Its not implemented in the right way @MichaelO.

Comment: `K` is a float number (constant) @TimofeyChernousov

Comment: @J.Do Then it should be `k * (np.exp(n) - alpha)` instead of `(k * np.exp(n) - alpha)`, if `n <= 0`.

Comment: could you post the right way to do it? @Unatiel

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need `numpy.where` for you goal.
Also keep in mind, numpy arrays could be used for vector operations directly (most times).

Sample code below:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: n = np.random.random(10)-0.5

In [3]: n
Out[3]:
array([ 0.15714377, -0.30756307,  0.02925383, -0.05156817, -0.32182295,
       -0.32772489,  0.15692736, -0.24274195, -0.19055825,  0.25264444])

In [4]: beta=1.0

In [5]: K=2.0

In [6]: np.where(n<=0, beta*K*(np.exp(n)-1), beta*n)
Out[6]:
array([ 0.15714377, -0.52952701,  0.02925383, -0.10052219, -0.55034698,
       -0.55887755,  0.15692736, -0.43105215, -0.34700477,  0.25264444])

In [7]:
```

From `numpy.where` [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

> numpy.where(condition[, x, y])
>
> Return elements, either from x or y, depending on condition.

Comment: Thanks for the help!.. what about the derivative?, which is the correct way to implement it?

Comment: @J.Do please define what value of derivative you expect, when n=0, n=1, and in range (0;1)? It is more related to the statement of your problem than to implementation.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the function and its derivative you can follow below procedure:

```
fun = np.where(n<=0, beta*K*(np.exp(n)-1), beta*n)
derivativ = np.where(n<=0, beta*K*(np.exp(n)), beta)
```

you can also use scipy.misc.derivative.https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html